# assigning variables to MVC view class?

Tags: php, templates, variable-assignment

i'm building a simple php MVC with MVC basic concept

while building the view class i tried to built a simple function which let me pass variables from the controller to the view

```
<?php

class View {
    protected $data = array();

    function __construct() {
        //echo 'this is the view';
    }
    public function assign($variable , $value)
    {
        $this->data[$variable] = $value;
    }

    public function render($name, $noInclude = false)
    {
        extract($this->data);
        if ($noInclude == true) {
            require 'views/' . $name . '.php';    
        }
        else {
            require 'views/header.php';
            require 'views/' . $name . '.php';
            require 'views/footer.php';    
        }
    }


}
```

in my controller class i used to use like this

```
class Index extends Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function index() {
        $this->view->assign('title','welcome here codes');
        $this->view->render('index/index',true);
    }
```

the render function just working fine but there is a problem with the assign function because when i tried to print out the variable from the view it shows nothing

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Test Code</title>
</head>
<body>
<? echo $title;?> 
some text here
</body>
</html>
```

i tried to change the protected variable within the View class to public but it didn't effect the problem and i still can't print out any variables from the controller

Answer (score 1):

it shows nothing because you require the view inside the View::render function, so to access your data you should write

```
<?php echo $this->data['title']; ?>
```

to avoid this, inside your render function you should create variables from the data array. I mean something like

```
foreach($this->data as $key => $value) {
  $$key = $value;
}
```

note: the code above can't live inside your "extract" function because of variables scope.